# How can I use the js skip page method to pass params(request data)?

Tags: javascript, python, django

How can I use the `self.location` or some method to pass data(request) to the views.py?

Because in my js, I use `self.location=/api/buy_products` to skip the page, and in the page, I want to render the data to the skiped template.

How to do with that?

My code is below:

In js:

```
self.location = '/api/buy_product/'
```

In my views.py:

```
def buy_product(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'app/buy_products.html' , # there I want to pass the request's data)
```

But how can I use the `self.location` to pass the data to the `buy_product` function?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to pass url parameters with self.location.  Go ahead and give it a shot and see if it works.

JS

```
self.location = '/api/buy_product?data1=my_data&data2=12345';
```

FLASK

```
@app.route('/api/buy_product', methods=['GET'])
def buy_product(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        data1 = request.args.get('data1')
        data2 = request.args.get('data2')
# Whatever you want to do at this point

        # If you want to render a template with the data...
        return render_template('template.html', data1=data1, data2=data2)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have two questions. 1) in the `views.py` I want to render other template with the data, and switch to the rendered template.  2) if I want use post method.  how to do with them?

Comment: I added a template render to the above code sample.  If you want to receive  data via a http post you need to add 'POST' to your methods keyword argument with @app.route.  To access the data you can use request.form.get('data1').  [Flask code samples here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)

Comment: Can I use the post method to do that?